# FTP connection to directory failed

Tags: ftp, directory-listing, dedicated-server

I am curently testing one dedicated server in which I can join it by this ip address `http://IPADDRESS/~niremco/`

and there I can see the index.html.

I have also a cpanel which gives me the settings to make a ftp connection.

I add a user and in the configuration it gives me the option to connect with

```
user: admin
pass: the password
host: ftp.niremco.co.vu
port: 21
```

When I try it though it fails:

```
Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is your current location
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
Command:    PASV.
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (93,*,*,*3,195,93)
Command:    MLSD
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

Anyone could help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you use `list` instead of `mlsd`?

Comment: You mention "IP Address", but you have a named host in your connection details? (Which incidentally doesn't resolve.)

Comment: @DavidPostill where is this option?

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios http://www.nsftools.com/tips/RawFTP.htm#LIST. It might be `ls` depending on the ftp server (https://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/ftp.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys i found the solution and i joined the folder.

The solution is simple. You push `Edit->Settings`.
Then click `FTP` and push `Active` on transfer mode.
then go to `"Activate Mode"` (under FTP) and click `"Limit Local ports used by Filezilla"`
and to the Lowest Available port put `"30000"`
and to the highest `"35000"`

Then push OK and i connected my filezilla!